# In a ring where $(a-b)^2 = a - b$ for fixed $a,b$, then $(a-b)(a+b) = 1 \iff a^2 - b^2 = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(A,+,\cdot)$ be a ring where $(a-b)^2 = a - b$ for fixed $a,b$. Then $$(a-b)(a+b) = 1 \iff a^2 - b^2 = 1.$$

I was able to prove one implication:

Proof ($"\Rightarrow")$

We have that $(a-b)^2(a+b) = a-b = (a-b)(a+b) = 1$ thus $a-b = 1$ so $a+b=1$. Then $a + b - (a - b) = 1 - 1 = 0 = 2b$;

But since $a-b = 1$ we get $a = b + 1$ so $a^2 = b^2 + 2b + 1 = b^2 + 1$ so

$$a^2 - b^2 = 1$$.

Any tips for the other implication?

Comment: Why in your ring there is $1$? It's not necessary.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: it is quite necessary, for having a unity is an axiomatic requirement for the algebraic structure known as a ring; those algebraic structures which are almost as rings with the exception of the existence of the unity should be referred to as pseudo-rings and are to be treated as associative $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I think even it can be not associative. It seems that we say about different structures.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: the question posted is clearly referring to the algebraic structure comprising an abelian group written additively and a monoid written multiplicatively such that the multiplication be bilaterally distributive with respect to the addition, in other words to a typical ring. Considering any other algebraic structure which might even be non-associative is totally unrelated to this specific problem.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I see the following. If for any $x$ we have $x^2=x$ so for any $x$ and $y$ we have $(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2.$ All these in non-associative ring without $1$.

Comment: What you don't seem to understand is first of all that **one does not call** a non-associative non-unitary $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra a ring. One simply doesn't. That there might be people who dare speak of non-unitary rings (I for one disagree with that practice), true, but in any case there is no such thing as a not necessarily associative ring!!!!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: second of all, your remark about some algebra whose every element were an idempotent is irrelevant to the exercise discussed here. This exercise states that there exists **a specific pair of elements** $a, b$ whose difference is an idempotent, not that all elements are idempotents.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I agree with your second comment. About the first: it's depend on definition only.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: in principle every notion depends on its definition, agreed, however the definition of the species of algebraic structures known under the name of rings is already fixed once for all and leaves one with absolutely no spare room whatosever to speak of ''rings without unity'' or ''non-associative rings''. A ring will always have a unity and will always be associative, and any structure that fails to satisfy either of these properties no longer is a ring. That is the definition and the only one there is.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I think the Lie's ring it's a very interesting structure. What about alternative rings? I don't agree with you!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: All those structures which you mention are algebras, not rings. Calling them rings is totally improper.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Of course, but we can work also with rings and it's also interesting.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: If you grant me an ''of course'' and I am right in saying that they are algebras, **not** rings, then there is no such thing as a ''Lie ring'' or an ''alternative ring''. The correct terminology is ''Lie algebra'' or ''alternative algebra''.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ All these for you. I studied Lie's ring and alternative rings. My teacher is professor  G.V.Dorofeev.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: My full esteem for your professor and with no intention to be disrespectful towards you either. It might be that in your mother tongue (or that in which you have received education in higher mathematics) you use the same term for typical rings (those associative and unitary) as you do for particular types of algebras (such as Lie algebras or alternative ones). However this is not the custom in English (neither is it for instance in Romanic languages, such as French, Romanian).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103023/discussion-between--and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idempotents are always a joy to work with. For the converse implication denote $a-b=e$ and notice that $e$ is an idempotent by hypothesis; substituting $a=b+e$ in the relation $a^2=b^2+1_A$ leads (after a few simple calculations and cancellations) to $e+be+eb=1_A$ and hence to 
$$eb+be=1_A-e \tag{1}$$

Multiplying relation (1) by $e$ **on the left as well as on the right** yields

$$eb+ebe=ebe+be=0_A \tag{2}$$

and hence to $eb=be=-ebe$.

Since $b$ and $e$ commute, $b$ and $a=b+e$ must also commute and thus one can factor the difference of squares 
$$1_A=a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$